# Find fails to find files below 1M but works fine with 'k' units

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have created file named 1.txt and it is 9kb in size:

```
stat 1.txt
  File: `1.txt'
  Size: 9322            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-06-26 10:12:47.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2015-06-26 10:12:47.000000000 +0100
Change: 2015-06-26 10:12:47.000000000 +0100
```

When I run `find` command with option `-size -100k` with k units, the file is found:

```
#find . -type f -size -100k
#./1.txt
```

When I use `M` units and `-size -10M` file is still found:

```
#find . -type f -size -10M
#./1.txt
```

But when I try to find files that are less than 1M in size, suddenly `find` doesnt find this file:

```
#find . -type f -size -1M
#
```

And yes, my version of find (`find (GNU findutils) 4.4.0`) supports the `M` unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because the units are represented as integers, and "less than 1" is 0, so it searches for files up to 0megs in size.

Counter intuitive for sure, but probably retained for backward compatibility with the distant past.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.  The `find` on my machine (MacOS, so it's a BSD `find`, I think) does not seem to have this problem.

Comment: I tried on Solaris, but find does not have k, G or M units so go figure!... I'm surprised BSD is different to Solaris TBH.

Answer (score 1):

The size is rounded up to an integer number of units of space.  In your
example,

```
find . -type f -size -10M
```

means, files with size <=9M,

and

```
find . -type f -size -1M
```

means, files with size <=1M,
which in fact means 0M because fractional units (for instance 0.5M) are
not supported.

Following is extracted from gnu find manual:

```
-size n[cwbkMG]
     File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following
     suffixes can be used:

     `b'  for  512-byte blocks  (this is  the default  if no
          suffix is used)

     `c'  for bytes

     `w'  for two-byte words

     `k'  for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)

     `M'  for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)

     `G'  for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)

     The size  does not count  indirect blocks, but  it does
     count  blocks in  sparse  files that  are not  actually
     allocated.  Bear in mind that  the `%k' and `%b' format
     specifiers of -printf  handle sparse files differently.
     The `b' suffix always denotes 512-byte blocks and never
     1 Kilobyte blocks, which  is different to the behaviour
     of -ls.

     The  + and  - prefixes  signify greater  than and  less
     than, as usual.  Bear in  mind that the size is rounded
     up  to  the  next  unit. Therefore  -size  -1M  is  not
     equivalent to -size -1048576c.  The former only matches
     empty  files,  the  latter  matches  files  from  1  to
     1,048,575 bytes.
```